# POST parameters to php application

Tags: php, post, poster

I am looking for a small app / add on / software that allows me to post parameters to php (so that I can test directly). I currently use POSTER add on firefox, but it appears a beginner project that lacks lots of features.

What do guys use ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I think looking for a specialized tool that solves a particular technical problem should also come under a fair stackoverflow question. so thats a fair question imho. if not, what other place is right for questions like these? programmers.stackxchange... maybe?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy exactly. thanks for your comment. actually, I got the answer to my question and I am using postman. Something which I might now got/known if not asked.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Postman, works fine:
http://www.getpostman.com/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try Postman: http://getpostman.com/

It allows you to make HTTP requests and set the number of parameters. Its easy to use and has a good UI. I use the Chrome extension.

Comment: it has only Chrome Extension and not seperate stand alone app ?

Comment: yes, (afaik) it is only available as a Chrome web store app.

Answer (score 0):

My most favourite is Live Http Header For Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ , It comes with Replay option aswel , which i dont find in other addons.